# XCode SPM - product [product] required by package [package] target [target] not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I use SPM in my project and want to integrate [Texture](https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture). My project is divided into different modules using SPM. I want to use Texture only in one.

The problem is that Texture does not support SPM. I forked from this [PR](https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/pull/1928) that supports SPM. I've successfully integrated Texture in my project, but can't use it.

My `Package.swift`:

```
let targets: [Target] = [
    .target(name: "MyTarget", dependencies: ["Texture"]),
]

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14), .macOS(.v10_15)],
    products: targets.filter { !$0.isTest }.map { .library(name: $0.name, targets: [$0.name]) },
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Texture", url: "https://github.com/bejeri4/Texture.git", .branch("spm")),
    ],
    targets: targets)
)
```

When I add Texture as a dependency to my local package, I get the following error:

> product 'Texture' required by package 'MyPackage' target 'MyTarget'
> not found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in the dependencies of your target you need to specify a product of the package Texture, not the package name itself. The products are AsyncDisplayKit and AsyncDisplayKitIGListKit:

So you should modify the targets to use one of the products like this:

```
let asyncDisplayKit = Target.product(name: "AsyncDisplayKit", package: "Texture")

let targets: [Target] = [
    .target(name: "MyTarget", dependencies: [asyncDisplayKit]),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you saved my day! After following your suggestion I got new error: "dependency 'AsyncDisplayKit' in target 'MyTarget' requires explicit declaration; reference the package in the target dependency with '.product(name: "AsyncDisplayKit", package: "MyTarget")'. "
To fix it I had to do the following:
'let asyncDisplayKit = Target.product(name: "AsyncDisplayKit", package: "Texture")' and then use it in MyTarget.
Could you please update the answer?

Comment: However I've got a new issue. I can't access all the classes. For example I can use 'ASNetworkImageNode' from 'AsyncDisplayKit', project builds successfully. I can't use 'ASVideoNode', getting the following error: "Cannot find type 'ASVideoNode' in scope"

Comment: This is expected since you have not defined AS_USE_VIDEO in the preprocessor definitions, also in order for someone that uses the library you see all the header definitions you should add in the publicHeadersPath their path, the ASVideoNode is fined in Source/ASVideoNode.h so the Source needs to be added.

Comment: But it's added in headerSearchPath in Package.swift (https://github.com/bejeri4/Texture/blob/spm/Package.swift). What do you mean in 'preprocessor definitions'? Could you explain me in details what should I do?

Comment: Try and add in the sharedDefines an extra define like this: .define("AS_USE_VIDEO", to: "1"),

Comment: I've added but still have the same issue.

Comment: I seems that the files are Objective-C++, can you try and add the same settings in cxxSettings for each target? (*Copy* the cSettings: argument and change the name cSettings->cxxSettings)

Comment: Still the same. Could you please check my Package.swift - https://github.com/bejeri4/Texture/blob/spm/Package.swift

Comment: I was able to fix it finally. AS_USE_VIDEOS was disabled in ASAvailability.h - I don't know why. I enabled it there and now it works.